# How to implemente a menu with 2 levels codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, menu

I'm trying to implement a menu with 2 levels , the categories for programs ;
Example : 
Parent 1: News 
1.1:local
1.2:international

[image]

My problem is that after every click the values change for the same category ..i hope that u understand & sorry for my bad english :)

After one click :
[image]

After the 2sd click on the same item:
[image]

here is my code

**Model**

```
public function get_categories($parent_id) {
    return $this->db->select('id,parent_id,category_title_fr,category_title_ar,categorie_trie')
                    ->from($this->table_categories)
                    ->where('parent_id', $parent_id)
                    ->order_by('parent_id')
                    ->get()
                    ->result();
}

public function get_categorieschild() {
    return $this->db->select('id,parent_id,category_title_fr,category_title_ar,categorie_trie')
                    ->from($this->table_categories)
                    ->where('parent_id','0')
                    ->get()
                    ->result();
}
```

**Controller**

```
    $data['cat_niveau1'] = $this->listeprogram->get_categorieschild();
    $this->load->view('templates/ar/template', $data);
```

**View**

```
foreach ($cat_niveau0 as $cat0) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.base_url().'index.php/program/programme_chaine_ar/'.$cat0->id.
            '" class="menu-button menu-drop"><span class="menu-label">'.$cat0->category_title_ar.'</span></a>';
    echo '<div class="menu-dropdown menu-dropdown1"><ul class="menu-sub">';
    foreach ($cat_niveau1 as $cat1) {
        if ($cat0->id == $cat1->parent_id) {
            echo '<li><a href="'.base_url().'index.php/program/programme_chaine_ar/'.$cat0->id.'/'.$cat1->id.
                    '" class="menu-subbutton"><span class="menu-label">'.$cat1->category_title_ar.'</span></a></li>';
        }
    }
    ?>
    <?php
        echo '</ul></div></li>';
}
```

Comment: After editing your code, in view I noticed where you were closing `</li>` tag...!!!It should be `echo '</li></ul></div>';`

Comment: And your question is not clear... Pls improve your problem statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't see where you are passing cat_niveau0. Then, you should either create your data with both levels in the controllers and pass it as a multidimentional associative array, or you could just pass cat_niveau0, then in the view

```
foreach ($cat_niveau0 as $cat0) {
# $cat1 = # get array through model based on cat0

}
```

Note: Also you have very strange names for your models: the one that is get_categories should be get_categorieschild and viceversa, maybe your're getting a little mixed up with which is which :)